# How can I know which subdomain is being requested and react accordingly?

Tags: redirect, asp.net-core, directory

I have a simple forum. What I'm trying to do is when someone goes to `website.com/thread/1234` I return a page containing posts from an SQL database. The problem is that I don't know how to see what subdomain is being requested to reply with the correct thread. Making dummy pages which return the posts is not an option here.

Comment: Do you use ASP.NET Core MVC?

Comment: Yes, and the pages are razor

Comment: Take a look at the [`HttpContext.Request.Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.host?view=aspnetcore-2.2) property. You can usually access it through just `Request.Host` within controllers and Razor pages.